# Find lists of almost equal values in list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, cluster-analysis

I have a 1D numpy array, and I want to find the sublists/subarrays that contain almost equal values. That means they don't differ from each other more than a tolerance. I mean there is one central point in the solution from which all other points don't differ more than tolerance. For instance if I have `[1.0, 2.2, 1.4, 1.8, 1.5, 2.1]` and tolerance `0.2` the desired outcome is `[[1.4, 1.5], [2.1, 2.2]]`. The following function does the job I think:

```
import numpy as np


def find_almost_equal(input, tol):
    sorted = np.sort(input)
    result = []
    for i, v1 in enumerate(sorted):
        result.append([])
        for j, v2 in enumerate(sorted):
            if v2 - tol < v1 < v2 + tol:
                result[i].append(v2)

    result = [r for r in result if len(r) > 1]

    for i, r1 in enumerate(result):
        for j, r2 in enumerate(result):
            if set(r2).issubset(set(r1)):
                del result[j]

    return result


test = np.array([2.6, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 1.1, 1.4])
tolerance = 0.15

almost_equal = find_almost_equal(test, tolerance)
print(almost_equal)
```

The outcome is `[[1.1, 1.2], [1.4, 1.5], [2.5, 2.6]]`. With `tolerance = 0.25` the outcome is `[[1.1, 1.2, 1.4], [1.4, 1.5], [1.8, 2.0, 2.2], [2.5, 2.6]]`.

When a point belongs to several sublists my algorithm does not always give the correct result. For example with input `[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]` and `tolerance = 0.2` the output is `[[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]]`, while the expected outcome is `[[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]]`.

The question: Is there an easier way to do this (preferably in numpy)? And how can I do this correctly?

Comment: For `tolerance = 0.25`, how is `[1.1, 1.2, 1.4]` a valid solution? Isn't `1.4 - 1.1 > 0.25`?

Comment: The term you are searching for is "clustering". But it's not an easy task, if you want reliable and reproducible results. Especially, you are giving not enough information, what your want. How do you interpret your tolerance? Over the complete cluster (ie `max - min <= tolerance` for each cluster) or if there is one element `x` in the cluster that is within the tolerance of the current element `c`, add `c` to the cluster? Furthermore any restrictions on the size/number of clusters? Because depending on the order you traverse your elements, you may or may not receive different clusters ...

Comment: @Tanishq Chaudhary Maybe the explanation is not clear. I mean there is one central point in the solution from which all other points don't differ more than tolerance, in this case that point is 1.2. I will add this to the question.

Comment: What if the array is: `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5` with `tolerance = 0.15`?

Comment: What if multiple solutions exist? Which is 'THE' solution? e.g. with `tol = 10` and `test = [1,5,6,7,8,12]` what would you expect? `[1,5,6,7,8]`, `[5,6,7,8,12]`, `([1,5,6], [7,8,12])` , ... ?

Comment: @Julien I would like to have the largest subset, in this case it would be `[1,5,6,7,8,12]`. The central point would be one of `5,6,7 or 8`. The second part of my function tries to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more concise way of doing this, using a bit more NumPy functionality, is to make a array of differences (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705180/1862861)), like:

```
def find_almost_equal(inp, tol):
    # create array of differences
    inpa = np.sort(inp)
    diff = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(inpa, inpa))
    
    # get precision of float type
    prec = np.finfo(inpa.dtype).eps * 10
    
    # loop over rows in diff array (except first and last)
    l = []
    for row in diff[1:-1]:
         # get values within tolerance (accounting for floating point precision)
         r = inpa[row + prec  < tol].tolist()
         if len(r) > 1:
             for i, prev in enumerate(l):
                 # make sure list isn't subset of previous lists
                 if set(r).issubset(prev):
                     break
                 elif set(prev).issubset(r):
                     # add in longer lists
                     del l[i]
                     l.append(r)
                     break
             else:
                 l.append(r)
    return l
```

This gives:

```
find_almost_equal([2.6, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 1.1, 1.4], 0.15)
[[1.1, 1.2], [1.4, 1.5], [2.5, 2.6]]
find_almost_equal([2.6, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.5, 1.1, 1.4], 0.25)
[[1.1, 1.2, 1.4], [1.2, 1.4, 1.5], [1.8, 2.0, 2.2], [2.5, 2.6]]
find_almost_equal([1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4], 0.2)
[[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]]
```